# Correlation of dataframe with itself

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
a=pd.DataFrame([[name1, name2, name3, name4],[text1, text2, text3, text4]],
               columns=(['names','texts']))
```

I have implemented a function to perform a cosine similarity between the words in each text using [GloVe](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/).

```
def cosine_distance_wordembedding_method(s1, s2):
    import scipy
    import scipy.spatial
    vector_1 = np.mean([glove[word] if word in glove else 0 for word in preprocess(s1)], axis=0)
    vector_2 = np.mean([glove[word] if word in glove else 0 for word in preprocess(s2)], axis=0)
    cosine = scipy.spatial.distance.cosine(vector_1, vector_2)
    return 1 - cosine
```

Now, I want to apply this function to all rows of my dataframe and compare the texts column with itself. So the resulting dataframe should be something like (namely a correlation matrix):

```
      name1 name2 name3 name4
name1 1     0.95  0.79  0.4
name2 0.95  1     0.85  0.65
name3 0.79  0.85  1     0.79
name4 0.66  0.65  0.79  1.00000
```

**I have done 2 ways to implement this and they are very slow. I want to know if there's another maybe faster.**

First way:

```
df = a.texts.apply(lambda text1: a.texts.apply(lambda text2: cosine_distance_wordembedding_method(text1, text2)))
```

Second way:

```
# Create a dataframe to store output.
df = pd.DataFrame(index=a.index, columns = a.index)

# Compute the similarities
for index1, row1 in a.iterrows():
    for index2, row2 in a.iterrows():
        df.loc[index1, index2] = cosine_distance_wordembedding_method(row1["eng_text"], row2["eng_text"])
```

Answer (score 0):

`scipy.spatial.cdist` is vectorized. So you can calculate all the vector representations for the texts and use `cdist` once:

```
from scipy.spatial import cdist

vectors = [np.mean([glove[word] if word in glove else 0 for word in preprocess(s1)] for s1 in df['texts'] ]

distance = 1 - cdist(vectors, vectors, metric='consine')
```

Remember that this way might require a lot of memory, specially when you have a big text data.